# How To Get a Notification mail to wordpress admin

Tags: php, html, wordpress, audit-logging

How To Get a Notification mail to wordpress admin when i update anything from wordpress wp-admin

Comment: http://pippinsplugins.com/wp-logging/ i just found this solution interesting

Answer (score 0):

You could also take a look at Stream: http://wordpress.org/plugins/stream/ - Unfortunately, it does not send emails by default, but it is very pretty and organized. You also need to make sure you have at least PHP 5.3 running.